# Performance Using Hyper-V to build in Android Studio

Tags: android, windows, performance, android-studio, hyper-v

This is a very general question for anyone who uses a virtual machine to build android stuff. I'm running Windows 8.1 64-bit in a Hyper-V VM with 2 cores and 2 gigs of RAM dedicated to the VM (which I could expand if necessary). All that is installed on it is Android Studio (for complicated/unknown reasons, I can't run it on my main image). It works fine except that build times are in the *minutes* instead of seconds like I'm used to. It's really slowing down my development (I'm still just learning, so I make a lot of mistakes that require rebuilds).

Does anyone have any tips for optimizing Hyper-V or Android Studio builds that might cut my build times down (they range from 3 minutes minimum up to 12 minutes for a VERY simple app)?

Thanks in advance, and apologies about the extremely general question!

Comment: Does your CPU support Virtualization Instructions?
Have you made sure that virtualization instructions have been enabled on your host PC?  
Have you made sure that Hyper-V is set to use the optimized instruactions?
How much RAM is available on the Host PC?

Comment: I enabled the virtualization in the bios (I had to to get Hyper-V to start). I've got the MSI P67-GD80 (MS-7672) mobo and Intel Core i7 2600K. I'm not sure how to set hyper-v to optimize instructions. I've got 16GB available system memory (2 is reserved for the VM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't require all the windows 8.1 features in the android development environment, then install Microsoft Server 2012 instead and then install additional required features only. It will improve the performance and speed dramatically.

Comment: That's a great idea. I really don't need almost any windows features. I thought about doing a linux VM, but I'm more familiar with windows so I figured start with what I know instead of compounding more things I'm not as familiar with.

Comment: well..then I highly recommend server 2012. also please avoid server 2008 etc. because older versions of the server may not have supporting frameworks and many other components which you will need in development environment. Good luck...